# bash: adduser: command not found [Debian Buster]

Tags: debian, users, useradd

**Question**: What is the most-ideal way to add new users in Debian? `adduser` appears to be missing on my system, any tips?

**Log**:

`bash: adduser: command not found`

---

**Edit**:

`adduser` does appear to be installed

```
adduser is already the newest version (3.118).
```

Is is possible to manually execute it as a binary? Where is the applications stored?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you edit the question to include also the exact command-line (incl. prompt) you used and which led to this error message? It may help identify the problem. E.g.: adding a user is a process reserved to the system administrator `root`, and in the current form of the question, it is not apparent if you were `root` user or gained the necessary admin rights via a `sudo` call (hence the questions/remarks of the other contributors).

Answer (score 43):

Use `su -l` or `su -` to start the root shell with an environment similar to a normal 'login' shell. This includes initializing the environment variable `$PATH` for user `root` instead of simply inheriting it from the normal (non-sudo) user who does not have `/sbin` on her `$PATH`. See `man su` or https://linuxconfig.org/command-not-found-missing-path-to-sbin-on-debian-gnu-linux.

This is how to enable sudo after a fresh install of Debian 10:

```
$ su -l
# adduser <your_username_here> sudo
# logout
```

Then, log out of the Desktop Environment and log in again.

Answer (score 11):

Adding `sbin` to path seems to at least temporarily fix the problem for me:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:usr/local/sbin"
```

---

Or try executing `/sbin/useradd`

Comment: Thank you very much! Your work around did it for me. The only other thing that I had to do was to use the SUDO command to add the new user.

Answer (score 0):

`which adduser` will tell you where the bin is located.

You should be root when trying to add a user.

Alternatively you can use the `useradd` command, also as root.

Comment: The problem appears to be that `useradd` is not found.

Comment: What user are you trying to execute the command as? If you are not the root user, certain directories are not in your $PATH (such as /sbin and /usr/sbin)

Comment: also if you omit the - after su it could have this affect